# Nestjs sequelize inject multiple repository

Tags: typescript, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm new to the Nestjs and typescript, I would like to know how to simplified the code below?
As you can see the code below, it will insert multiple REPOSITORY to the `users.module.ts`, and Inject to the contractor in the `users.services.ts`

**users.module.ts**

```
import {USER_REPOSITORY, USERSTORE_REPOSITORY, STORE_REPOSITORY} from '../constants';
@Module({
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService, [
  {
    provide: USER_REPOSITORY,
    useValue: Users,
  },
  {
    provide: USERSTORE_REPOSITORY,
    useValue: UserStores,
  },
  {
    provide: STORE_REPOSITORY,
    useValue: Stores,
  }
 ],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
```

**users.services.ts**

```
import {
  USERSTORE_REPOSITORY,
  USER_REPOSITORY,
  STORE_REPOSITORY,
} from 'src/core/constants';
export class UsersService {
   constructor(
      @Inject(USER_REPOSITORY) private readonly userRepository: typeof Users,
      @Inject(USERSTORE_REPOSITORY)
      private readonly userStoresRepository: typeof UserStores,
      @Inject(STORE_REPOSITORY) private readonly StoresRepository: typeof Stores,
    )

   async getAllUsers(): Promise<Users[]> {
      const result = await this.userRepository.findAll<Users>({
         include: [
            { model: this.userStoresRepository, include: [this.StoresRepository] },
         ]
      });
      return result;
   }
}
```

I feel like I'm creating repeating code if I have multiple table to be injected. Is there any simplified way to do this? or is it possible to make it like `const userRepository =  new xxxx` when I need it in the function, instead of Inject in the contractor all the way?
For example:

```
//users.services.ts
  export class UsersService {
     constructor()
      async getAllUsers(): Promise<Users[]> {
         const userRepository = new xxxx
         const userStoresRepository = new xxx
         const storesRepository = new xxxx
         const result = await userRepository.findAll<Users>({
            include: [
               { model: userStoresRepository, include: [storesRepository] },
            ]
         });
         return result;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why does it feel like repeating code? And is there a reason the `UsersService` needs all of these repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Include the entity instead of the repository, you don't need to import them then

```
export class UsersService {
     constructor()
      async getAllUsers(): Promise<Users[]> {
         const result = await userRepository.findAll<Users>({
            include: [
               { model: userStoresRepository, include: [Stores] },
            ]
         });
         return result;
      }
  }
```

You can simplify again by using the repository pattern for consistent data access in your app, here you would define your includes in your providers and it would be abstracted away from your service. This would be useful if you are following OOP/ domain driven design principles and want to define your business logic at class level instead of in the services.

```
export class UsersService {
     constructor()
      async getAllUsers(): Promise<Users[]> {
         const result = await userRepository.findAll<Users>();
      }
  }

import {USER_REPOSITORY, USERSTORE_REPOSITORY, STORE_REPOSITORY} from '../constants';
@Module({
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService, [
  {
    provide: USER_REPOSITORY,
    useFactory: () =>
      new SequelizeRepo<User>(UserRoleAssignment, [Stores]),
}
```